# How to recreate database tables from amazon snowflake in amazon redshift with SQL or Python? (recreate all ot once, not one by one)

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to move database tables to amazon redshift, but in order to do that, I have to recreate the empty tables in redshift.

See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-data-create-tables.html).

What I need is a way to recreate them all at once somehow. Not like the way it is done in the link above, one by one since there are many tables.

The original database is in amazon snowflake. I need a simple solution, not a fully automatized service since this is a one time thing that needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

On Snowflake, you can execute:

```
SELECT get_ddl('database','{name of database}');
```

This will get you the entire schema, table, views, etc. CREATE or REPLACE statements from Snowflake.  You may need to do some find/replace on data types or some other things that may differ between Snowflake and RedShift, but it's the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA has the details about tables - names, columns, data types, keys, comments.  You can use "dynamic sql" to splice them together into a create table statement.  Here's an example:

```
select 
    'create or replace table ' || max(table_name) || ' (\n' 
    || listagg('  ' || column_name || ' ' || data_type, ',\n')
    || '\n);'
from my_database.information_schema.columns
group by table_name
;
```

See this Snowflake [article](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/using-snowflake-information-schema/) for more inspiration.